# Creating a link to a file on a form but file address is stored on another table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have made a form that is used as an inter-department sign-off sheet for controlled documents on the network. The database already includes a table with a hyperlink field for each document's location. The table also has a text field of the document id. My form is storing its information in a different table, but I am hoping that I can still use the hyperlinks from the first table instead of creating new links in the second table.

My google searching lead me to [this forum post](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/655416-command-button-locates-hyperlink-table-then-opens) that showcased a single line using FollowHyperlink and DLookup:

```
Application.FollowHyperlink DLookup("Document_ID", "Documents", "Document_ID = '" & Me.DocumentID.Value & "'")
```

Document_ID is the field that holds the hyperlink.

Me.DocumentID is the textbox that the user types in and the code runs when this field is clicked.

I have tried multiple variations of the code including wrapping table fields in brackets "[]", using either the hyperlink field or the text field for the criteria, using Like instead of = (along with asterisks around Me.DocumentID). All of which result in a run-time error 2471:

> The expression you entered as a query parameter produced this error:
>   'Document_ID'

Which makes me think that Dlookup doesn't like hyperlink fields as I can pull other fields just fine. What am I missing? Or is there a better way to reference hyperlinks in a different table?

Comment: reference the table in your dlookup  `FollowHyperlink DLookup("[tableName]![Document_ID]", "Documents", "[tableName]![Document_ID]= '" & Me.DocumentID.Value & "'")`

Comment: I still get the same error, just now it says [Documents]![Document_ID].  (Documents is the name of the table btw.)

Comment: That 2471 error could happen if your `Documents` table does not include a field named `Document_ID`  If you test with the following expression, how does Access respond? ... `Debug.Print DLookup("Document_ID", "Documents")`

Comment: @HansUp, I get the same error for the Debug.Print line. There's definitely a field with that name, the value I'm testing with in Me.DocumentID works, I can filter the table to that value, AND the hyperlink works from the table.

Comment: Just to double check in case Document_ID _isn't_ the name for some reason, I opened up a form that uses the Documents table and has a control with the hyperlink field. The control source says "Document_ID" so that name should work.

Comment: @LuxClaridge I created a `Documents` table with a single hyperlink field named `Document ID` (notice space in name).  I stored a link to Stack Overflow in the only row I added to that table.  Afterward, `Debug.Print DLookup("Document_ID", "Documents")` gives me the 2471 error.  But when I use the proper field name, `Debug.Print DLookup("[Document ID]", "Documents")` shows me the field's text value ... `Stack Overflow#https://stackoverflow.com/#`

Comment: @HansUp So maybe the underscore is a problem?

Comment: @LuxClaridge Perhaps.  But fundamentally the problem is your `Documents` table  does **NOT** include a field named `Document_ID`.  Open the table in Design View and check spelling of the field name.

Comment: OMG, I found it. There's a space in between the underscore and ID. The space was too small for me to notice in design view. I only figured it out _after_ copying the field name from design view and pasting into vba where spaces are more pronounced. But now I am getting a null error. Two steps forward, one step back lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to HansUp for pointing me in the right direction. Turns out that "Document_ID" didn't exist in the table. Instead the hyperlink field had a space between the underscore and ID ("Document_ ID") and I didn't catch it until copying the name from the table into vba where spaces are more pronounced.

The Dlookup would not work when using the hyperlink field in the criteria so the text field with the document id was used instead and changed my code to the following as .FollowHyperlink wouldn't take the whole field value (title#address)

```
Dim LinkText As String

LinkText = DLookup("[Document_ ID]", "Documents", "[DocID] = '" & Me.DocumentID & "'")
LinkText = Application.HyperlinkPart(LinkText, acAddress)
Application.FollowHyperlink LinkText
```

The control will now open the documents that exist (now to work on code to use for when the documents don't exist)